# Selecting multiple files in Catalina breaks the finder

Tags: macos, finder, catalina

[image: Activity Monitor while trying to select files]Both our MacBook Air 2015 and MacBook Pro 16inch with Catalina 10.15.3 and 10.15.4 run into problems when selecting a lot of files at once in Finder:

- When I select a few hundreds DNG photo files in a folder or SD card, the finder freezes, beachballs and takes a few minutes to become available again and select them. During that waiting time, the CPU becomes super hot and the fans spin up to max.
- Same when I select simple TIFF files in one folder. When I do that on the new MacBook Pro with Catalina, the Finder freezes and the fans spin... it takes so much waiting until the files are selected and I can then copy, delete, continue with my work.

PRAM, SMC reset, secure boot didn't change a thing.

- (My 2013 iMac 27inch with Sierra and Mojave handles this just fine, although as soon as I boot it into Catalina the same problems occur.)

I suspect the OS now has a problem with selecting a large number of files? The more complex the files (24MB DNGs versus 6MB TIFFs) the less of them you need to select for the finder to freeze.

Any ideas on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Done so far: 
PRAM, SMC, secure boot, new user, fresh install, login items removed, relaunch finder, first aid for Mac SSD. Replicable on different Macs with Catalina, no problem with other MacOS X Versions.

Comment: To reach Apple directly, see the Contact link at the bottom of apple.com. If your MacBook Pro was bought recently you might also able to get specific support by navigating through support.apple.com to report the problem.

Comment: @MarcYa  post a screenshot of activity monitor while such processing is going on

Comment: @nohillside Thanks, I've been through extensive testing with three advisors now. The standard tests have brought no change (PRAM, SMC, secure boot, new user, fresh install, login items removed, relaunch finder, first aid for Mac SSD) I'm more than sure this is about Catalina and not exclusive to my Mac at all. I have yet to report back to the advisor after doing first aid with the SSD.

Comment: @ankii I attached a screenshot to the original post.

Comment: @MarcYa I was doubting quicklook related stuff which goes crazy when previewing big files. I just force quit it whenever that happens, but here's it looks like it's a bug. Does It happen with any file type ?

Comment: I will create a test scenario and come back to you. So far I only have thousands of photo files to test it. I suspect it can happen with any file, the bigger or complex the file the less you need of them for it to happen. If others with Catalina could try it too it might help figure out if this is a major problem wit Catalina.

Comment: @ankii “Show preview column" unchecked totally eliminated the problem. 
I can confirm on all three Macs with Catalina that the removal of the preview column in columns-view eliminated the load on the CPU... I can cmd-A all 2000+ files with no delay: The columns view of the new Catalina Finder is the problem. In Sierra it showed a preview image of a single selected file and when you select several the preview column stayed blank. NOW in Catalina the preview column shows a summary of all selected files and a stack of preview pictures representing them.

Comment: /continued
This new preview column with it's information display about ALL selected files is causing the finder to go haywire... Selecting thousands of files in "list view" or DEACTIVATING the preview column in "column view" eliminates the problem. 
Having tested this on three Macs and having a fourth Mac of a friend try and confirm the same thing, I'm now sure this is a Catalina problem affecting all of us, just not many will run into this workflow.

Comment: @MarcYa best is to change settings for such a folder to hide column, or use other views. glad you got a fix